# Ionic globally call function after Modal present

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to pop an alert box every-time after a modal is presented.

I know that I can do something like this `modal.present().then(()=>alert("Modal presented"))`

However, I have more than 30 pages, which have the modalController. 
It is **inefficient** to add the promise calling to every pages.

Is there any way that I can **globally** customize the event after a modal box is presented, so that I need not to update all the pages?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a function to show modal in your **service**. Every you want to show a modal, use that function. So you can handle success callback for every modal presentation.
**yourProvider.ts**

```
showModal(component, data) {
    this.modalCtrl.create(component, data).present().then(() => {
      console.log("show modal success");
      //Add your alert here
      alert("Modal presented");
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log("show modal error", error);
    });
  }
```

Just call the function above whenever showing a modal:
**yourPage.ts**

```
this.yourProvider.showModal("SomePage");
```

Note that: This is just a suggestion. I did not use this way in real project show can not point out any downside of it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For this approach, but still, I need to change all the existing modal functions to the new `showModal()`.

Comment: Yes. I'm afraid of that it is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Lifecycle events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/), in your case probably ionViewDidEnter().